# Parallax effect created through JS is too smooth

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to make parallax effect for the background by using JS, because background-attachment is very laggy (for example, on Safari it doesn't work for an unknown reason, and on Android browser, when you scroll a bit, image of background gets bigger).

My code works well, but one minus is noticed: it's too smooth.
What happens in the real project: https://youtu.be/GuGiOV3qbvA

```js
function parallax() {
    document.body.style = `--check: ${window.scrollY}px`;
    requestAnimationFrame(parallax)
}
requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
```

```css
.wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://nd58.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/202204p2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: var(--check);
}

.placeholder {
    height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

    </div>
    <div class="placeholder">

    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Important to say, I use Swiper-Slider in real project. When I remove code of swiper, situation gets better. I suppose it's working like it is because of perfomance, but I have no idea how to fix this.

I'm expecting that background will moving with viewport without a delay.

Comment: add `transition: background-position-y 100ms ease-in-out;` to `.wrapper::before` - play with the numbers and easing as required

Comment: but I need to make that background is fixed at viewport and should moving immediatly without delay